# SAX парсер (достать значение атрибута из узла)

Tags: java, xml, sax

Есть код:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("узел1")) {
        Узел1 = true;
    }
```

Тут я достаю значение для данной конструкции XML документа:

```
<узел1>value</узел1>
```

Достаю это значение следующим кодом:

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (Узел1) {
        System.out.println("Узел1 : " + new String(ch, start, length));
        Узел1 = false;
    }
```

Все хорошо и прекрасно, но хотелось бы реализовать работу с атрибутами по следующей структуре XML документа:

```
<Узел атрибут = "это значение надо достать" атриубт2="и это тоже"/>
```

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут есть достаточно простой пример решения вашей задачи: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/sax/get-element-attributes-in-sax-xml-parsing/

Comment: Буквально минут 15 назад нашел этот пример и сделал ) Но все равно спасибо, второй день мне помогаете !